# For in loop not working with global namespace variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, canvas, for-in-loop

I'm working on a canvas animation/game and I am having problems with a for in loop in one of my functions. In the interest space I removed some code.

```
function LoadScene(){ // function with the issue
                console.dir(game.frames); //195 objects 0{}, 1{}, 2{}, etc.
                for (var prop in game.frames){
                    console.log(prop); //Does not get here
                    if (game.frames[prop].scene == game.currentScene){
                        game.sceneData.push(game.frames[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }

function LoadFrames(){
                //xhr request
                // if successs load json data into namespace variable
                // get canvas
                // drawImage Loading Screen
                // return true

}


function StartGame(){
   if(LoadFrames()){
       LoadScene();
   }
}
```

The for in loop just fails every time (never goes into the loop) even though there are items in the in the object. I thought it might have been a hoisting issue so I put all my variables into a namespace at the top of the script and rearranged my functions. I think it could also be a async issue since the function works when I use the debugger to step through the function, but if that is the case then I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: `just fails` in what way? error in the console? never enters the loop? castrates your dog?

Comment: *"I think it could also be a async issue"* - I think this is it. Can you call `LoadScene()` from within `LoadFrames()` Ajax code, or use a promise or callback mechanism to wait for the load to finish?

Comment: You need to call `LoadScene()` from the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function.

Comment: @JaromandaX It never goes into the loop, not unless I step into it using the debugger.

Comment: then the duplicate question will give you all you need to know

Answer (score 0):

```
function LoadFrames(){
            //xhr request
            // if successs load json data into namespace variable
            // get canvas
            // drawImage Loading Screen
            // return true
}
```

The `XMLHttpRequest` within `LoadFrames` may work asynchronously, whereas `LoadFrames` works synchronously. **`LoadFrames` always returns `true` immediately after sending the AJAX request**, regardless of if the frames(maybe you mean `game.frames`?) have been loaded; i.e. **it does not check the response of the request.**